# Is it possible to run a personalized command when Evolution receives new mail?

Tags: ubuntu, email, notifications, evolution

I'm using Evolution for reading my emails at my Ubuntu 9.10.
I would like to run a personalized command when it receives a mail, like checkgmail.

Example:
`blink --scrolllockled --rate {number-of-new-mail}`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create filters in Evolution that run commands.

I used this to suck out emails from a Microsoft Exchange server (that had IMAP disabled) - a filter-rule running deliver on new emails, followed by a filter-rule that marked the email as read.

It is called "Pipe to program" in [the documentation](http://www.novell.com/documentation/evolution24/?page=/documentation/evolution24/evolution24/data/usage-mail-organize-filters.html).